# Read Failed for Text file in Android Eclipse.Help me

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String data;
Writer sbuffer ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sbuffer=null;
        try {
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.config);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        sbuffer.append(data + "\n");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sbuffer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Am new bee for Android Development .I Tried to Read Textfile from drawable folder.It Shows Error Please help me out. and Please give code to read file line by line text from drawable folder

Comment: Dont use a Writer class, instead use StringBuilder to read it

Comment: Can i get Code to Save date to texfile in drawable folder ? @DJphy

Comment: i think u cannot write a file into drawable coz the resources folder on the whole will go into dex file(as an apk) u cannot edit it or write to it so can only be read...